# How to compress with boost zlib streaming data

Tags: c++, boost, zlib

I have a server and receive on it data from another server. This data must be compressed with zlib and sent by socket to third server. The third server uses gzip to decompress the data.

I use this function.

```
std::string compressData(const std::string &data)
{
   using namespace boost::iostreams;
   using namespace std;
   using namespace boost::archive::iterators;

   stringstream zippedOutputStream;
   filtering_ostream filteringStream;
   filteringStream.push(gzip_compressor());
   filteringStream.push(zippedOutputStream);
   stringstream stringStream;
   stringStream << data;
   boost::iostreams::copy(stringStream, filteringStream);

   return zippedOutputStream.str();
}
```

The third server receives two or more pieces at once. It tries to decompress the data with gzip but the result is only first piece. The other pieces are missing. How should I change compressData function to fix this problem.

Comment: This function seems to compress the whole data. So what are the pieces? If you split your data while sending, why not assemble the pieces in the third server and then decompress as a whole?

Comment: This function creates a complete gzip stream. Separate call, separate gzip stream. All data that should be decompressed with single call must be compressed with single call.

Comment: On a related note, the function is unnecessarily complex. You don't need to write the data to `stringStream` and copy it, you can write the data directly to the `filteringStream`. That also means you don't have to compose the two pieces to one `string`. You can instead create the `filteringStream` in an object, write the two pieces separately and pick up the compressed result.

Comment: Stylistic note: Having two identifiers that only differ in case, `stringStream` and `stringstream` in your case, is bad style and makes the code difficult to read. Since the function is reasonably short, using shorter (abbreviated) names for local variables would probably be OK here.

Comment: did you fix compressData method? if yes, post it here